# Set initial value for datetimepicker bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I cant set initial value `2016-10-17T00:00:00.000+00:00` for the datetimepicker with format `MMMM DD, YYYY`.

http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/3753/

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try writing the value in the format you specified:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" value = "October 17, 2016" />
```

**value = "October 17, 2016"** is in "MMMM DD, YYYY" format.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/3763/)

EDIT:
You can also pass the date in datetimepicker options:

```
date: 'October 17, 2016'
```

or

```
date: new Date(2016, 9, 17) //months start from 0, so October = 9
```

Whole constructor:

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  format: 'MMMM DD, YYYY',
  date: new Date(2016, 9, 17)
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/3768/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question but please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/3765/) and let me know.

```
$(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: "2016-10-17T00:00:00.000+00:00"

            });
        });
```